# How to stop OnSwipeListener from catching OnClickListener's events?

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-gridview, ontouchlistener

I have a gridView in which I store pictures. Now I want to change the content of the gridView when the user swipes (which I did with gridView.invalidateViews() ), but I also need to start a new activity when the user clicks on a picture.
Unfortunately, the OnSwipeListener catches some  ClickEvents, so the ClickListener doesn't work correctly anymore. Here is the code:

```
final GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //PULL UP THE HERO STATS ACTIVITY HERE
            //setContentView(R.layout.activity_herostats);

            Intent startHeroStats = new Intent (typeHeroes.getContext(), HeroStats.class);
            int heropath = ActiveHeroGridInt[position];
            //int heropath = getResources().getIdentifier(Agility[POSITION], "drawable", getPackageName());
            startHeroStats.putExtra("heropathkey", heropath);
            startActivity(startHeroStats);
        }
    });

    //SET UP THE SWIPE LISTENER
    gridView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(MainActivity.this) {
        /*public void onSwipeTop() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "top", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }*/
        public void onSwipeRight() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        public void onSwipeLeft() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (ActiveHeroPage<2) {
                ActiveHeroPage+=1;
            }
            ActiveHeroGrid=StrengthInteger;
            ActiveHeroGridInt=Strengthint;
            gridView.invalidateViews();
        }

        /*public void onSwipeBottom() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "bottom", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }*/

    });
```

How can I solve this problem? Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `onClickListener` and `OnTouchLister` together.

Comment: Yes, you can, if you correctly differentiate events and dispatch them down the interested parties for that event.

Comment: onTouchLister is enough to detect onClick. But how to use it with OnItemClickListener?

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski How do  I have to differentiate the events then?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using intercept touch events and return true for blocking it false for allowing it. Using that method you can diff btw vertical/horizontal swipes, block onclick and pass on swipe and vice-versa.

Comment: I actually figured it out just a few hours ago. Problem was I returned true already in the onTouchListener so that blocked the onClickListener